# Jquery change image id attr by click

Tags: jquery

I have a problem :

HTML :

```
    <div class="img-container">
        <img id="mainImage" src="assets/img/01.png">
    </div>
```

and a button with `class="change"`

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".change" ).click(function() {
            alert('test');
            $("img#mainImage").attr("src", 'assets/img/02.png');
        });
  });
  </script>
```

This works for the alert but not the attr. I can't change the img... and after i would like change for another image ( 03.png,04.png etc etc )

Comment: I can't see any error in your code. It should work fine.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: your code is fine. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/7omo6oct/

Comment: Your code is working fine, http://jsfiddle.net/zLbtv2o3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a counter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1; // initialize counter by 1.
    $( ".change" ).click(function() {
        alert('test');
        var num = counter <= 9 ? '0'+counter : counter; // will return 01-09 and after 11,12 etc.
        $("img#mainImage").attr("src", 'assets/img/'+num+'.png');
        counter++; // counter increment.
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

html:

```
<div class="img-container">
        <img class="mainImage" id="mainImage" src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg">
    </div>
```

js:

```
var $mainImage = $("#mainImage");
if($mainImage){
    $mainImage.click(function(){
        $(this).attr("src","https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWZuPMvJ8bOAdo30nNZSe2sofDiOLrX1J-GkzeX5GgTJusxcFE");
    });
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6ydge42/1/)